# Setting UIView frame equal to View.Frame or View.Bounds doesn't use entire screen

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I created a form in `Xamarin.Forms` and then used a `PageRenderer` in Xamarin.iOS to display live camera feed using `AVCaptureSession`. I set a `UIView` Frame equal to the View.Frame and then added a sublayer `AVCaptureSessionPreviewLayer` to that `UIView`. Testing on an iPhone 7 the Camera feed takes up the entire screen but testing on an IPad the camera feed is only in the middle leaving a big margin on the left and right, but not on the top or bottom.
When debugging the Bounds that are set they equal 0, 0, 768, 1024. Even though the x and y origin are both 0 it does not start in the top left corner.

How can I fix this issue? Is there a way instead of creating a completely new UIView in the code behind I can just set the `AVCaptureSessionPreviewLayer` to show inside of a `Xamarin.Forms` control?

UPDATE: I added another control and set the origin to 0,0 and it's in the top left corner. So I would assume that me adding a sublayer is the cause of the improper origin and width.

Comment: When were you performing the drawing? You will likely have different results doing drawing if you execute the same code in `ViewDidLoad`, `ViewWillAppear`, `ViewDidLayoutSubviews` since the view hasn't figured out it's correct dimensions until `ViewWillAppear`. Something to be mindful of!

Comment: I tried moving my code that initializes the UI to ViewWillAppear from ViewDidLoad and it did not change anything unfortunately. Thanks for the suggestion though!

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the layer's frame equal to its super layer's bounds, just as you do with the view.  You should do this in the layoutSubviews method of the parent view, so that the layer responds to any auto layout size changes in the parent view.

Comment: I set the UIView Frame equal to the View.Frame. And then i set the AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer's Frame equal to the UIView.Frame. So debugging and checking the values the View.Frame is 0, 0, 768, 1024. The UIView is the same and so is the CapturePreview. That's why im stuck.

Comment: Setting the Sublayer's Frame equal to View.Frame has the same result

Comment: the frame is always in the superview/superlayer's coordinate system.  The bounds is the local coordinate system.  Even though they may be coincidentally the same in your case, thats not always true so it should be subview.frame = superview.bounds.  But in any case are you using aspect fit for your video gravity? https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avcapturevideopreviewlayer/1386708-videogravity

Comment: I am not using videoGravity. I followed this example here https://github.com/messier16/FullCameraPage. This worked while testing on my IPhone 7 but now the view isn't working correctly

Comment: Maybe another question can solve this issue. Is there a way that i could set the AVCameraPreview to a control inside a Xamarin.Form control? then i would have a XAML layout and would it all screens quite easily